# Evaluate 2 consecutive integers in an array into a character

Tags: c

What I want the program to do is to evaluate the 2 consecutive integers after another in a set of array, then convert these integers to a corresponding character.

For example, if I have `array[10] = {4 2 3 2 5 3 5 3 6 3}`, the first 2 ints 4 2 will be converted into "H", 3 2 = E, 5 3 = L and so on until it prints the word HELLO. The program should accept a list of integers.

This is what I've done so far..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int i=0, j=0, k=0;
  int array[1000];
  char space;

  printf("Input integers to convert into a string: ");
  do {
      scanf("%d%c", &array[i], &space);
      i++;
  } while(space != '\n');


  for(/*what should I include here?*/)
        if (array[0] == 2 && array[1] == 1)
          printf("A");
        else if (array[0] == 2 && array[1] == 2)
          printf("B");
        /* and so may else ifs*/


}
```

Comment: wow ! you can't simply say "if first number is 2 and second is 1, print A", you must try to convert theese two numbers into 21, then use some simple function you find in c doc to convert your decimal into a char.

Comment: I don't understand you conversion from integer to characters. You are saying the first to are 4 and 2, which character do you want?

Comment: If you think you need a long chain of if's like that...back up and rethink what you're doing. For this task, you don't need any. As for loop controls, your input loop ends up with `i` being the count, so you need to loop over that many elements.

Comment: What's the pattern here? Are the numbers assigned to the letters just random? And if so, how do you expect us to help?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Instead of going through the for loop one int at a time, it would probably be best to do two at a time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 2){
    if (array[i] == 2 && array[i + 1] == 1)
      printf("A");
    else if (array[i] == 2 && array[i + 1] == 2)
      printf("B");
    /* and so may else ifs*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that converts the integers to the characters.

```
char int_to_char(int val)
{

    if(val == 21)
        return 'A';

    if(val == 22)
        return 'B';

    if(val == 42)
        return 'H';

    if(val == 32)
        return 'E';

    if(val == 53)
        return 'L';

    if(val == 63)
        return 'O';


    // I don't see you pattern, so I don't know which value
    // is which character
    return '?';
}
```

I don't see your pattern here.

Then your loop would look like:

```
// i is the number of entered values
// making sure that the end condition is even
for(int j = 0; j < i&1 ? i - 1 : i; j += 2)
{
    printf("%c", int_to_char(array[j] * 10 + array[j+1]));
}
```

This would print `HELLO` with the input `4 2 3 2 5 3 5 3 6 3`.